# How to install magento2.3.5-p1 in ubuntu20.04

Tags: installation, magento2.3.5-p1, ubuntu

I want to install magento2.3.5-p1 on ubuntu 20.04 LTS so can anyone having idea of how to do this please share with me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can follow this https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-install-magento-2-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 document provides a very genuine document to setup store in ubuntu or localhost. Kindly follow link [Installation quick reference (tutorial)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install-quick-ref.html)

If this helps then hit like.

Thank you,

Hiren Patel